# $parent.myFunction not returning row as parameter in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using knockoutjs for the first time in an attempt to have a list of tasks and then to be able to click on one to show it in a popup form. The issue I'm having is with data-bind="click: $parent.edit", which calls ToDoListViewModel/edit.

When I first started writing the list code, it would pass in the current row's todo object as the first parameter into the edit function. After adding the second view model for my add/edit popup form, it no longer behaves this way. Calling $parent.edit still calls the edit function, however now it passes in an empty object { }.

It seems like I'm running into some sort of conflicting bindings issue, any ideas?

Here is the to do list html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" data-bind="visible: isVisible">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>To-Do</th>
                        <th>Estimate</th>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        @if (Model == null) { <th>Property</th> }
                        <th>Tenant</th>
                        <th style="display: none;">Assigned To</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: todos">
                    <tr data-bind="visible: isVisible()">
                        <td><a class="pointer" title="Edit To-Do" data-bind="click: $parent.edit, text: Task"></a></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: FormattedAmount"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: FormattedDueDate"></td>
                        <td data-bind="visible: $parent.showPropertyColumn, text: PropertyName"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: TenantName"></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary pointer default-click-action" data-bind="click: $parent.markComplete">Mark Complete</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="pointer" data-bind="click: $parent.edit">Edit To-Do</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="pointer" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Delete To-Do</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is the popup html:

```
@model Housters.Schemas.Models.Property.Listing

<div id="popup" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" data-bind="with: form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveTodo", "Properties", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>To-Do Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" data-bind="value: todo().Id" />
        <input id="originalListingId" type="hidden" value="@(Model != null ? Model.IdString : "")" />

        <div class="control-group @(Model != null ? " hide" : "")">
            <label class="control-label" for="listingId">Property</label>
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.DropDownList("listingId", ViewBag.Listings as SelectList, "None",
                    new Dictionary<string, Object> { { "data-bind", "value: todo().ListingId" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="tenantId">Tenant</label>
            <div class="controls">
               <select id="tenantId" name="tenantId" class="span11" data-bind="value: todo().TenantId">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                </select>
                <p class="help-block">Is this task related to a certain tenant?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="amount">Estimate to Complete</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" id="amount" name="todo.Amount" maxlength="10" 
                    class="span11 number" data-bind="value: todo().Amount" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="dueDate">Due Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="dueDate" name="todo.DueDate" maxlength="10" 
                    class="span11 date" data-bind="value: todo().DueDate" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="task">Task<span class="required-asterisk">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea id="task" name="todo.Task" rows="4" class="span11 required" data-bind="value: todo().Task"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn pointer" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a id="mark-complete-popup" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="visible: (todo().Id && !todo().IsComplete), click: markComplete">Mark Complete</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

And lastly, here is the javascript defining the view models:

```
function ToDoList () {

    if(!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) 
        return new arguments.callee();

    var parent = this;
    this.showCompleted = ko.observable(false);
    this.tenantFilter = new PropertyTenantFilter();
    this.viewModel = {
        list: new ToDoListViewModel(),
        form: new ToDoFormViewModel()
    };

    this.init = function () {
        //get all tenants.
        utils.block($("#grid-content"), "Loading");
        this.tenantFilter.init(function () {
            //initialize view model.
            ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel);
            //setup controls & events.
            $("#dueDate").datepicker();
            $("#listingId").change(this.tenantFilter.getByListing.bind(this.tenantFilter)).change();
        } .bind(this));
    };

    function ToDoListViewModel() {
        //init.
        var self = this;
        self.todos = ko.observableArray([]);

        //computed.
        self.showPropertyColumn = ko.computed(function () {
            return $("#originalListingId").val().length == 0;
        });
        self.isVisible = ko.computed(function () {
            return _.find(self.todos(), function (todo) { return todo.isVisible(); }) != null;
        });

        //operations.
        self.add = function () {
            //set form field values.
            parent.viewModel.form.fill(new schemas.ToDo({}, parent));
            //show popup.
            $("#popup").modal("show");
        };
        self.edit = function (todo) {
            console.debug("edit: " + JSON.stringify(todo));
            //set form field values.
            parent.viewModel.form.fill(todo);
            //update tenants dropdown for selected listing.
            parent.tenantFilter.getByListing();
            //show popup.
            $("#popup").modal("show");
        };
        self.markComplete = function (todo) {
            parent.markComplete(todo);
        };
        self.remove = function (todo) {
            var result = confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete this To-Do?");
            if (result) {
                //save changes.
                utils.ajax(basePath + "properties/deletetodo",
                    { id: todo.Id },
                    function (success) {
                        //refresh results.
                        self.todos.remove(todo);
                        //show result.
                        utils.showSuccess('The To-Do has been deleted successfully');
                    }
                );
            }
        };
        self.toggleShowCompleted = function () {
            parent.showCompleted(!parent.showCompleted());
            $("#showCompletedTodos").text(parent.showCompleted() ? "Show Active" : "Show Completed");
        };
        self.update = function (todo) {
            var existingToDo = _.find(self.todos(), function (item) { return item.Id() == todo.Id(); });
            existingToDo = todo;
        };

        //load todos from server.
        utils.ajax(basePath + "properties/gettodos",
            { id: $("#originalListingId").val(), showCompleted: parent.showCompleted() },
            function (results) {
                var mappedTodos = $.map(results, function (item) { return new schemas.ToDo(item, parent); });
                self.todos(mappedTodos);
                $("#grid-content").unblock();
            }
        );
    }

    function ToDoFormViewModel() {
        //init.
        var self = this;
        self.todo = ko.observable({});
        utils.setupPopupForm(self.saved);

        //operations.
        self.fill = function (todo, isEdit) {
            //set form field values.
            self.todo = todo;
            if (todo.Id()) {
                //update tenants dropdown for selected listing.
                parent.tenantFilter.getByListing();
            }
            //show popup.
            $("#popup").modal("show");
        };
        self.save = function (todo) {
            self.todo = todo;
            $("#form").submit();
        };
        self.saved = function (result) {
            var todo = new schemas.ToDo(result.todo, parent);
            if (result.isInsert)
                parent.viewModel.list.todos().push(todo);
            else
                parent.viewModel.list.update(todo);
            utils.showSuccess("Your To-Do has been saved successfully.");
        };
        self.markComplete = function (todo) {
            parent.markComplete(todo);
        };
    }

    this.markComplete = function (todo) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure that you want to mark this To-Do complete?");
        if (result) {
            //save changes.
            utils.ajax(basePath + "properties/marktodocomplete", {
                    id: todo.Id()
                },
                function () {
                    todo.IsComplete(true);
                    //show success.
                    utils.showSuccess('Your To-Do has been marked completed');
                } .bind(this)
            );
        }
    }

    this.init();

}
```

Comment: Couldn't you reduce your code to the minimum which showcase your issue? Maybe in a JSFiddle>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to replace:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.edit"
```

with

```
data-bind="click:$root.viewModel.list.edit"
```